# How can I make this script better?

Tags: linux, shell-scripting

I was wondering if there is a better way to create a file other than appending each line to the file. I did it this way so I can preserve readability, however, there is no indentation. Is there a way to create a file and input multiple lines at once?

```
if [ -d "/srv/www/$1" ]; then
 echo "Domain name already exists!"
else 
 mkdir -p /srv/www/$1/public_html; 
 mkdir -p /srv/www/$1/logs; 
 echo "<VirtualHost>" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1
    echo "ServerAdmin support@$1" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1
    echo "ServerName $1" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1
    echo "ServerAlias www.$1" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1
    echo "DocumentRoot /srv/www/$1/public_html/" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1
    echo "ErrorLog /srv/www/$1/logs/error.log" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1
    echo "CustomLog /srv/www/$1/logs/access.log combined" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1
 echo "</VirtualHost>" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1
 a2ensite $1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a heredoc.

```
cat > /etc/apache2/sites-available/"$1" << EOF
<VirtualHost>
ServerAdmin support@$1
...
EOF
```

Comment: 8 minutes until you get best answer

Answer (score 1):

Heredoc as stated in answer #1 or just have your echo go across multiple lines

```
echo "line 1
line2
line3" > file
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's readability you're after, have you considered splitting it out into multiple files? Have a "template" file that you can edit that is copied over with your shellscript.

```
## /path/to/vhtemplate
<VirtualHost>
    ServerAdmin support@#1
    ServerName #1
    ServerAlias www.#1
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/#1/public_html/
    ErrorLog /srv/www/#1/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /srv/www/#1/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Example script:

```
if [ -d "/srv/www/$1" ]; then
 echo "Domain name already exists!"
else 
 mkdir -p /srv/www/$1/public_html; 
 mkdir -p /srv/www/$1/logs; 
 cp /path/to/vhtemplate /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1
 sed -i -e 's/#1/$1/' /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1
 a2ensite $1
```

Comment: I like this a lot, and I upvoted your answer. Using templates is a great idea too.