# What is wrong? "Syntax error: unexpected end of file"

Tags: debian, shell-scripting

I keep getting this error, do you guys know what is wrong?

`rapache` is an alias for restart apache

```
mugbear:/usr/bin# cat /usr/bin/mkdomain                                         
if [ -d "/srv/www/$1" ]; then
        echo "Domain $1 already exists!"
else
        mkdir -p /srv/www/$1/public_html
        mkdir -p /srv/www/$1/logs
        cat >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/"$1" << EOF
        <VirtualHost removed:80>
                ServerAdmin support@$1
                ServerName $1
                ServerAlias www.$1
                        DocumentRoot /srv/www/$1/public_html/
                ErrorLog /srv/www/$1/logs/error.log
                CustomLog /srv/www/$1/logs/access.log combined
        </VirtualHost>
        EOF
        a2ensite $1
    rapache
fi
mugbear:/usr/bin# mkdomain test.com                                        
/usr/bin/mkdomain: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your heredoc never ends since the terminator is not at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I don't see a terminator in the other answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/196557/how-can-i-make-this-script-better
Could you show me me an example? Also, I cannot seem to find a manual on EOF.

Comment: The `EOF` must be the only thing on the line. No spaces before, and none after. And you want to find a manual for `<<`, not `EOF`.

Comment: Ahh. I see, it looks weird without the indentation, but it works. Thakns!

Comment: Generally heredocs are not indented. It's understood that they're not really part of the script.

Answer (score 3):

```
someFile <<EOF
...
EOF
```

*works*

---

```
    someFile <<EOF
    ...
    EOF
```

*will not work*

---

```
    someFile <<-EOF
    ...
    EOF
```

*works*

---

See '[man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)' and the [Bash Reference Manual, section "3.6.6 Here Documents"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) for details on `<<-EOF`. Note that the indentation of the heredoc terminator *must* be done using tabs, not spaces.

Comment: Good point re: `<<-EOF`. I fixed your formatting and added the detail about tabs for you.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `<<-EOF`. Also see [Bash Reference Manual, section "3.6.6 Here Documents"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) for an explanation. I added some links to your answer.